# Injected HttpContext is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is honestly mindblowing, I can't get it to work.
The context is always null, wherever it is injected...

Do I have to add an instance of the context in Startup.cs? If Yes, how?

**Originating calls**

```
services.AddTransient<SessionService>();
Toast.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<SessionService>());
_session.Set("foo", "bar");
```

**Toast Class**

```
public class Toast
{
    private static SessionService _session;
    public static void Configure(SessionService sessionService)
    {
        _session = sessionService;
        Messages = new List<ToastMessage>();
    }
}
```

**Session Service**

```
public class SessionService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    public SessionService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _accessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Set(string key, string value)
    {
        _accessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString(key, value);
    }
}
```

**Exceptions**

```
System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

**Stacktrace**

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at EveOps.Services.SessionService.Set(String key, Byte[] value) in C:\Users\youri\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EveOps\src\EveOps\Services\SessionService.cs:line 25
   at EveOps.Toast.set_Messages(List`1 value) in C:\Users\youri\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EveOps\src\EveOps\Toast\Toast.cs:line 41
   at EveOps.Toast.Configure(SessionService sessionService) in C:\Users\youri\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EveOps\src\EveOps\Toast\Toast.cs:line 18
   at EveOps.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in C:\Users\youri\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EveOps\src\EveOps\Startup.cs:line 162
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.BuildApplication()
```

Comment: Did you try to resolve Toast by injection ? Can you post the Exception and its StackTrace ?

Comment: @aguafrommars haven't tried that, stacktrace edited in the OP.

Comment: ok, it's because there isn't HttpContext, on startup, if you call the `Set` method on StartUp, you'll always get a null `HttpContext`. I can have a context only during a request.

Comment: @aguafrommars I see. Thank you. Got it working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @aguafrommars for stating the obvious; the context is only valid for requests, and even though I knew that, my understanding of DI and services is not yet at a good level.

The solution for my problem (pseudo):

```
App.Use() {
   Toast.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<SessionService>());
}
```